# Can a C# UserControl be saved in a database field (not the data - the control itself)

Tags: c#, sql, controls

We populate the front end-content of our website from a SQL database. We have a need to include either a placeholder or a usercontrol within the raw content that is returned from the database table content field.

For example:

This is page content, page content, page content `'usercontrol:myControl runat="server" id="123" variable1="abc"'` more page content, more content, etc.

Note that we have the proper format for the usercontrol, the above code is abbreviated so it would post correctly.

The reference to the usercontrol location is already on the page, we just need the embedded version for placement and content specific variables. If we put the usercontrol directly on the page, it works but if we pull the same control from the database it doesn't resolve - it stays in its text form.

Is it possible to include a `"runat=server"` control that will properly resolve within the results returned from the database? In searching for an answer we found many links to pulling data into a usercontrol but not actually embedding the usercontrol within the data.

Comment: You can't do this. The aspx/ascx is parsed by the runtime before you would have the ability to modify it from the code-behind. You're going to probably need to look into creating the control with Page.LoadControl("~/path/to/mycontrol.ascx") and setting it's before inserting it into the correct container for the page.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'll try your direction.